# Configure rsyslog client to send different log filename to a syslog-ng server

Tags: logging, rsyslog, syslog-ng

I have multiple servers with rsyslog configured to write logs to a remote syslog-ng server configured like this:

```
# Log anything of level info or higher.
# Don't log private authentication messages!
*.info;authpriv.none                                    @<IP-SERVER>

# The authpriv file has restricted access.
authpriv.*                                              @<IP-SERVER>
```

and the syslog-ng server configured:

```
destination d_remote {
    file ("/var/LOG/$HOST-$YEAR$MONTH$DAY");
};
```

but with this configuration the client write both logs to the same file.

Is it possibile to configure the client (i cant modify the syslog-ng server) to separate the logs to different files?

Answer (score 0):

For this, you'll have to modify the configuration of the syslog-ng server (basically, you need a filter that separates the different kinds of logs into separate files).

An ugly hack on the client side could be to encode this information into the HOST field of the log message (so that the server will treat them as coming from different hosts), but I don't know if it is possible in rsyslog or not.